# Как число в двоичной системе преобразовать в число в десятичной системе в C

Tags: c++, c

Как число в двоичной системе преобразовать в число в десятичной системе в C.

Comment: Скорее всего ваш вопрос заблокируют т.к. 1) Это не сайт "сделай мне программу", что написано на [обзорной станице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) 2) У вас нет конкретного условия (Как происходит ввод данных например). Учтите это, задавая следующий вопрос

Comment: В интернете кстати существует множество решений вашей задачи, [например](https://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread426904.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать очень просто:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main (void)
{
   char s[] = "0100 0x6fffff";
   char *end;
   long a = strtol (s, &end, 2);
   long b = strtol (end, &end, 0);
   printf ("%ld %ld \n", a, b);
   return 0;
}
```

А вот [тут](https://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread426904.html) есть множество решений (как на C, так и на C++) вашей задачи.